# How to download KsirK skins?

Tags: command-line, games

I want to download another skin for this Risk game, but the button doesn't work.
Is there is a command line for downloading and installing all the other maps?

Answer (score 1):

From [KsirK - Development Information](http://www.kde.org/applications/games/ksirk/development) you can get to the [git source](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdegames/ksirk/repository/revisions/master/show/ksirk) site, see screenshot below, where you can [download](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdegames/ksirk/repository/revisions/master/show/ksirk/skins) the skin folder/files, that you then can add manually.

The skin installation `dir`, taken from the `root/ksirk/skins/CMakeLists.txt@master` is:

```
add_subdirectory( default )
 # add_subdirectory( static ) 
 # add_subdirectory( realpol )

install(FILES skinsdir DESTINATION ${DATA_INSTALL_DIR}/ksirk/skins)
```

Also the old [web-index](http://download.gna.org/ksirk/) of the game might be of interest, depending on your version?!

[image]

Comment: found the data on the github page but there are no instructions on how to actually add the skins to ksirk.  I expected something in .config or .local but there was no KsirK folder and no button in the app to apply the downloaded skins.